# To launch my app when firebase notification or local notification received in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, alarmmanager, alarm, android-developer-api

I need to create an application to purpose manage alarm and I want when alarm fired my app opened and launched, or when firebase notification or local notification received my app launched.

Comment: Without tapping the notification in NotificationBar ?

Comment: You should add more details to your question, of what you have tried so far, and it will help others to help you properly.

Comment: yes actually without tapping the notification,